# Why are BLE IPSP nodes GAP peripherals?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ipv6

The BLE IPSP (Internet Protocol Support Profile) [specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=296307) requires that "nodes" support the GAP Peripheral role, while "routers" support the GAP Central role. This means that end-nodes will beacon and routers will respond to those beacons.

This seems like the opposite of WiFi, where routers beacon and end-nodes respond to those beacons. What's the rationale behind swapping that role for BLE IPSP? It seems like it would be more battery efficient to have the end-node listen for beacons instead of transmitting beacons.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning is way more power demanding than advertising. When advertising, you only have to turn on the radio a few hundred microseconds to send the packet, and then go back to sleep. Scanning requires the radio to be turned on the same fraction of time as you want probability a packet should be captured.

You are however correct that the logic seems to be a bit opposite to how wifi setup works. I guess that's because peripherals usually don't have a display and user interface to select which router to join.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the maximum beacon period? If the maximum beacon period was short enough then scanning could be cheaper than beaconing. Also, to form a connection a peripheral must turn on its receiver to listen for any responses. Without knowing some BLE parameters it's not obvious to me that scanning is cheaper than beaconing.

Comment: Your second paragraph may get at the real reason nodes are expected to be peripherals, though

Comment: To establish a connection from the peripheral side is very cheap. It sends an advertising packet and the central must answer to this with a connect request within a window of only 4 microseconds. If the advertiser didn't get any response, it turns off its radio. A scanner on the other hand usually scans for several milliseconds before it sleeps a bit before it continues again. Please read the Bluetooth spec for the link layer to learn all the details.